# Как в ассемблере зеркально отобразить биты?

Tags: ассемблер

Как в Assambler зеркально поменять старшие и младшие биты в числе

Comment: практичный способ — создать предварительно вычисленную таблицу для отражения байта, а сами байты в числе поменять самому... а для тренировки можно и ручками побитово развернуть. самый простой способ — это цикл и сдвиги в/из `cf`...

Comment: как слева приписать число?

Comment: слева к чему? какое число?

Comment: есть число a - для простоты пусть будет 1001001b после первой итерации будет 100100 в cf будет 1, и нужно 1 приписать с лева

Comment: циклическим сдвигом с переносом (`rcr`/`rcl`).

Comment: mov ebx,17
rcr ebx,1  и на выводе 8

Comment: к чему это?....

Comment: Что эта команда не автоматически переносит младший разряд в старшие, а сохраняет значение в cf, которое нужно ручками как-то магическим способом приписывать

Answer (score 5):

Самый быстрый и практичный способ, если есть возможность выделить лишние 256 байт — это создать предварительно вычисленную таблицу для отражения байта, а сами байты в числе поменять ручками:

```
bit_reverse_table8:
 ;  00   01   02   03   04   05   06   07   08   09   10   11   12   13   14   15   
 db 00h, 80h, 40h, c0h, 20h, a0h, 60h, e0h, 10h, 90h, 50h, d0h, 30h, b0h, 70h, f0h,
    08h, 88h, 48h, c8h, 28h, a8h, 68h, e8h, 18h, 98h, 58h, d8h, 38h, b8h, 78h, f8h,
    04h, 84h, 44h, c4h, 24h, a4h, 64h, e4h, 14h, 94h, 54h, d4h, 34h, b4h, 74h, f4h,
    0ch, 8ch, 4ch, cch, 2ch, ach, 6ch, ech, 1ch, 9ch, 5ch, dch, 3ch, bch, 7ch, fch,
    02h, 82h, 42h, c2h, 22h, a2h, 62h, e2h, 12h, 92h, 52h, d2h, 32h, b2h, 72h, f2h,
    0ah, 8ah, 4ah, cah, 2ah, aah, 6ah, eah, 1ah, 9ah, 5ah, dah, 3ah, bah, 7ah, fah,
    06h, 86h, 46h, c6h, 26h, a6h, 66h, e6h, 16h, 96h, 56h, d6h, 36h, b6h, 76h, f6h,
    0eh, 8eh, 4eh, ceh, 2eh, aeh, 6eh, eeh, 1eh, 9eh, 5eh, deh, 3eh, beh, 7eh, feh,
    01h, 81h, 41h, c1h, 21h, a1h, 61h, e1h, 11h, 91h, 51h, d1h, 31h, b1h, 71h, f1h,
    09h, 89h, 49h, c9h, 29h, a9h, 69h, e9h, 19h, 99h, 59h, d9h, 39h, b9h, 79h, f9h,
    05h, 85h, 45h, c5h, 25h, a5h, 65h, e5h, 15h, 95h, 55h, d5h, 35h, b5h, 75h, f5h,
    0dh, 8dh, 4dh, cdh, 2dh, adh, 6dh, edh, 1dh, 9dh, 5dh, ddh, 3dh, bdh, 7dh, fdh,
    03h, 83h, 43h, c3h, 23h, a3h, 63h, e3h, 13h, 93h, 53h, d3h, 33h, b3h, 73h, f3h,
    0bh, 8bh, 4bh, cbh, 2bh, abh, 6bh, ebh, 1bh, 9bh, 5bh, dbh, 3bh, bbh, 7bh, fbh,
    07h, 87h, 47h, c7h, 27h, a7h, 67h, e7h, 17h, 97h, 57h, d7h, 37h, b7h, 77h, f7h,
    0fh, 8fh, 4fh, cfh, 2fh, afh, 6fh, efh, 1fh, 9fh, 5fh, dfh, 3fh, bfh, 7fh, ffh

; ...

    xor bx, bx  
    mov bh, bit_reverse_table8[al]
    mov bl, bit_reverse_table8[ah]
```

Подобные таблицы можно сгенерировать написав небольшую программку на любом высокоуровневом языке программирования.

---

Если лишние 256 байтов выделить нельзя, то можно обойтись таблицей в 16 байт для ниблов (полубайтов в простонародии):

```
bit_reverse_table4:
;   00   01   02   03   04   05   06   07
 db 00h, 08h, 04h, 0ch, 02h, 0ah, 06h, 0eh, \
    01h, 09h, 05h, 0dh, 03h, 0bh, 07h, 0fh

; ...

    ; Перенесём отдельные ниблы в отдельные регистры
    mov dx, ax      ; dx := ax == _abcd_
    and dx, 0f0fh   ; dx := _0b0d_
    and ax, f0f0h   ; ax := _a0c0_
    shr ax, 4       ; ax := _0a0c_

    ; Исходное число получается разложено по ниблу в однобайтовые регистры:
    ; _abcd_ -> ah : dh : al : dl

    mov bh, bit_reverse_table4[dl] ; bx := _.Dxx_
    mov bl, bit_reverse_table4[dh] ; bx := _.D.B_
    shl bx, 4                      ; bx := _D.B._
    or bl, bit_reverse_table4[ah]  ; bx := _D.BA_
    or bh, bit_reverse_table4[al]  ; bx := _DCBA_
```

Для 32-х битных регистров все действия нужно повторить ещё раз, сдвинув исходный регистр и регистр назначения на 16 вправо и влево соответственно.

---

Если дополнительную память вообще использовать нельзя, то можно всё сделать побитово ручками. Самый простой (хотя обычно не самый эффективный) способ — это цикл и сдвиги в/из `CF`:

```
  mov ecx, 16
next_bit_loop:
  rcr ax, 1  ; Сдвиг следующего младшего бита ax в cf
  rcl bx, 1  ; Сдвиг текущего младшего бита из cf в младший бит bx
  loop next_bit_loop
```

В качестве бонуса в этом варианте, если добавить ещё один `rcr ax, 1`, то старое значение из регистра `bx` также окажется обращённым в регистре `ax`. Эффективности ради, цикл, конечно, можно развернуть.

---

Если заморочится или если на процессоре нет аналога `rcr` для x86, можно сделать всё это с помощью хитрых битовых манипуляций. На примере байта это будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
  ; al = _abcdefgh_

  ; x = ((x >> 1) & 0x55) | ((x << 1) & 0xaa) 
  mov dl, al   ; dl = _abcdefgh_
  shr al, 1    ; al = _.abcdefg_
  shl dl, 1    ; dl = _bcdefgh._
  and al, 55h  ; al = _.a.c.e.g_
  and dl, aah  ; dl = _b.d.f.h._
  or  al, dl   ; al = _badcfehg_

  ; x = ((x >> 2) & 0x33) | ((x << 2) & 0xcc)
  mov dl, al   ; dl = _badcfehg_
  shr al, 2    ; al = _..badcfe_
  shl dl, 2    ; dl = _dcfehg.._
  and al, 33h  ; al = _..ba..fe_
  and dl, cch  ; dl = _dc..hg.._
  or  al, dl   ; al = _dcbahgfe_

  ; x = (x >> 4) | (x << 4)
  mov dl, al   ; dl = _dcbahgfe_
  shr al, 4    ; al = _....dcba_
  shl dl, 4    ; dl = _hgfe...._
  or  al, dl   ; al = _hgfedcba_
```

Для объёмов больше байта аналогичный способ будет даже эффективней способа перекачки битов через `CF`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   mov eax, <input>

    xor ebx, ebx;

    l1:

    shr eax, 1;
    rcl ebx, 1;

    cmp eax, 0;
    jne l1;


 mov <output>, ebx
```